# HP eprint not properly printing A4

Tags: printing, printer

When I send an A4 PDF to the HP eprint service, it's printed by my printer as follows (see below). I went to [HP Smart](https://www.hpsmart.com/) but couldn't find any setting there to adjust the sheet size.

Has anyone had this issue before and was able to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most PDF readers have various options in the Print dialogue to select the how the page will fit on the paper. In Acrobat Reader DC, click the Size button, and then "Fit". Does that fix it?

Comment: eprint doesn't involve PDF readers. You simply email a PDF to your printer's email address.